# How do you load config settings from the database in Symfony2?

Tags: settings, symfony

I have a number of settings that are currently in the config.yml file.

Going forward I want to be able to develop an interface where administrators will be able to update these settings, so I want to be able to manage these settings through the database.

How would I be able to load these settings from the database into Symfony2 and where and when would I load them?

Cheers

Adam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html) that explains roughly how to do this (albeit briefly), in reference to loading in settings externally from Drupal. The basic idea is to do something like this in your config (example is yml):

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

then in `parameters.php` you can do whatever you need to to get your config, and set it as follows:

```
$container->setParameter('my.db.parameter', $value);
```

(taken from the cookbook, slightly modified).

Comment: Hi richsage, thanks for the answer that sounds great. Is there a good place you recommend to store the parameters.php file? Should it be part of a bundle or a service or should I have it as a stand alone php file. How would I then access the doctrine orm service? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Hi richsage, sorry just looked at the cookbook example and can see where the file should go.

Comment: I would say store your file in the `app/config` directory - at least your config is all together. I'm not sure how "available" services are at that point however, if at all, so not sure if you'd be able to do eg `$container->get("my.service")`. Might be worth a try though!

Comment: I will have a go at that. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Does anyone know how we would then access these parameters in the Twig templating engine.

Comment: Do you have to instantiate $container?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [UnifikDatabaseConfigBundle](https://github.com/egzakt/UnifikDatabaseConfigBundle). It creates a database structure that enable configuration of Symfony parameters straight from the database.

Comment: Great bundle! I was just about to develop something similar. Thanks for sharing! :)