# How do you access the Doctrine service in an imported parameters file in Symfony2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I asked a recent question about how to load your own parameters in Symfony2, which was answered here [How do you load config settings from the database in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925581/how-do-you-load-config-settings-from-the-database-in-symfony2/6926399), but I now need to know how to actually access the database in the import file.

I have tried using:

```
$container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Unfortunately, I then get a **"The service definition doctrine.orm.entity_manager does not exist."** error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work.

```
$this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

But only if Doctrine is enabled.

Have you the Doctrine Bundle in your kernel ? Have you uncommented the doctrine settings in config.yml ?

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for helping. The bundle is setup and used throughout my app. In my /app/config/config.yml file I am importing a /app/config/parameters.php file. In this file I want to be able to then load some parameters from the database using `$container->setParameter()` function. I wasn't sure if the Doctrine Bundle had been loaded at this point or not. Is there an alternative way of providing my settings from a database to my whole app?

Comment: Ok my answer was far away from that. Maybe you can try to plug your custom configuration after the kernel init ? There is some events you can listen like kernel.request (RequestListener::onKernelRequest).

Comment: Run `php app/console container:debug` to check if the Doctrine2 service is being loaded or not, and whether it is named accordingly.

Comment: Adam I'm having the same issue as you, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: clang1234, you should call $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();, the example in the question is obsolete, SF2 API has change.

Comment: Damien, the issue is not trying to call the em, it's trying to call the em while symfony is processing the config file. At that point in processing, doctrine isn't even an available service.

Answer (score 3):

After asking and looking around for a while the only solution I found to accessing doctrine while Symfony is still configuring its services is using [this bundle](https://github.com/opensky/OpenSkyRuntimeConfigBundle). Take a look at the readme as it describes a solution to the scenario we are both experiencing.

Comment: Hi clan1234, sorry for not responding sooner. I have been away. Thanks for your response. I will take a look.